# Raising the ship doesn't work

Tags: myst

I'm playing Myst:Masterpiece edition from GOG.

I have found the clues leading to the symbols of the leaf, the serpent and the insect/spider. But when I click to the corresponding buttons around the small ship, nothing happens.

I just checked that [walkthrough](https://youtu.be/c5Fxc72NVhM?t=1905) and I didn't see anything that seemed different from what I'm doing...

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Have you checked all the other buttons to make sure they're all off?

Comment: @qazmlpok thank you, that was the issue. I hadn't realized the buttons could be toggled on/off and had left some on when I first explored the island.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the solution is that some of the buttons were left on during an initial exploration of the island. The buttons mentioned in the question need to be on, and all the others off, for the ship to rise.